# Help with php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

heres my code

```
$cont = file_get_contents("users.txt");
$lines = explode("\n",$cont, true);
if(in_array('$name', $line)) {
    echo "Error user $name in database";
    exit;}
```

I have a file with users name in a text file then that get turned into an array ($lines)
I need it to search the array to see if the user name in in the text file

Comment: Not sure where your setting the $name variable in your code example, but you should not have the single $quotes around it.

Comment: Now you always use string '$name' and not a variable ? Your condition should look like "if (in_array($name, $lines))"

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $name is a string of the name you would like to find in the array you created from the file it should look more like this:

```
$cont = file_get_contents("users.txt");
$lines = explode("\n", $cont, true);
if(in_array($name, $lines)) {
    echo "Error user $name in database";
    exit;
}
```

I would personally recommend going to route of regular expressions though. Also, I can see the "explode" being a memory hog as the file grows and potentially slowing the site drastically.

I have not looked into this deeply, but if you are going flat file you may want to try something along the lines of http://www.niblr.com/php-flat-file-search-script/ if there will be a large amount of users in the system. Or even just running a regular expresion against the results of file_get_contents.